# Open Rate for App Push Notification is showing as 0% for iOS and Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-analytics, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

Currently, we are facing the challenge that the `open/open rate` is coming as 0 in Salesforce. We have also set `SFMCSdk.mp.setNotificationRequest(response.notification.request)` But we had not enabled `.setAnalyticsEnabled(true)`.

Also we want to know, if setAnalyticsEnabled is not yet set, how are we still seeing Sent, Delivered and Bounce Rates in Intellegence report.

Comment: Open a support case.

Comment: @BillMote can you please confirm where we can open a support case?

Comment: @Ankit See [Create a Support Case](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5)